# How set the onClick event in a ImageButton?

Tags: android, events, onclick, listener, android-imagebutton

I have created one image button in android, but when I am clicking on that button nothing is happening. I have set all the properties but still nothing is happening. So can you help me that where I am wrong.

***xml file***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <AbsoluteLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget39"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="3dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_x="312dp"
        android:layout_y="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="@drawable/search" />

    />
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

***search.java***

```
public class SearchData extends Activity {
ImageButton search; 

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_data);
        search =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.search);
        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()   {             
               public void onClick(View v)  {               
                try {
                    ConnectService();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();                    
                }               
               }  
             });
    }
```

Comment: you got some advance? I edit my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_x="312dp"
        android:layout_y="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="@drawable/search" />
```

As per your xml you should remove `android:onClick="onClick"` line from your Image button Xml.Then it will work because 1st priority will go for always onClick method what you mentioned in xml.

Answer (score 3):

in **XML File** (for example activity_main.xml)

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/search"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/home"
...
/>
```

in **Java File** (for example activity_main.java)

```
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // initiate and perform click event on button's
       ImageButton search = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.search);
       search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"search button is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

in your XML see the value of `android:onClick` and `android:id`:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:layout_x="312dp"
    android:layout_y="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="myFunctionName"
    android:background="@drawable/search" />
```

In your file.java See the name of function `myFunctionName` and the actions when the event is fired into the case `case R.id.search:`

```
public class SearchData extends Activity {
ImageButton search; 

  public void myFunctionName(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
      case R.id.search:
        try {
          ConnectService();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();                    
        } 
     break;
    }
  }

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           // code
  }

}
```

Comment: when i am writing your solution than i am getting error that "add unimplemented methods".

Comment: @rajeevpatidar just make a function in your code with the same name of the value of android:onClick="myFunctionName" in this case public void myFunctionName(View view) { }

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement Onclick listener to your activity

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_x="312dp"
        android:layout_y="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="@drawable/search" />
    />
```

No issue with this button

Change your activity as like below

```
   ***search.java***
    public class SearchData extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    ImageButton search; 

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_data);
            search =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.search);
            search.setOnClickListener(this);

  }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.search:
                  try {
                        ConnectService();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();                    
                    }              
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Hope it will work. if you have any doubt to implement this let me know

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `android:onClick="onClick"` from xml

Comment: you have given a good solution by noticing where the issue actually is.